# Сказка про белого бычка

Tags: фразеология

Есть такая присказка - "сказка про белого бычка".
В детстве я всегда хотела узнать, что же это за сказка такая, но оказалось, что никакой сказки про белого бычка не существует.
А откуда же тогда пошло это выражение? Была ли такая сказка?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сказка про белого бычка - это одна из [докучных сказок](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0):

— Сказать ли тебе сказку про белого бычка?

— Скажи.

— Ты скажи, да я скажи, да сказать ли тебе сказку про белого бычка?

— Скажи.

— Ты скажи, да я скажи! Сказать ли тебе сказку про белого бычка?

…Скажи...

Докучная сказка не похожа на обычную сказку, это текст или диалог, в которых бесконечно повторяется одно и то же. В диалоге рассказчик бесконечно повторяет свои фразы, чуть-чуть модифицируя текст, опираясь на "ответ" собеседника. Пример - сказка "Купи слона", где рассказчик просто повторяет ответ собеседника после "все говорят", заключая его просьбой купить слона.

— Купи слона!

— Что это ты придумал?

— Все говорят «что это ты придумал», а ты купи слона.

— Да ну тебя!

— Все говорят «да ну тебя», а ты купи слона.

Answer (score 1):

У попа была собака, поп ее любил, она съела кусок мяса, поп ее убил, и в землю закопал и надпись написал:
У попа была собака...

это без всякой опоры, рекурсия.